# Распознавание штрих кодов

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы написать программу для распознавания штрих кодов, подскажите с чего начать, спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Для начала

1. Ознакомиться с уже существующими opensource-проектами по созданию и распознаванию штрих-кодов.
2. Ознакомиться с типами штрих-кодов и схемами кодировки в них информации

**UPD1**: кто бы мог подумать, но по-английски штрих-код величается как 'barcode'
Пара ссылок на проекты:
[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), [Barcode generator](http://www.barcodephp.com/), [PHP Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2176-PHP-Web-interface-to-generate-barcode-images.html) и т.д.

Comment: ZBAR http://zbar.sourceforge.net/